# Parse resulting webpage Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I used Selenium webdriver in Python to input some text in search field and look for it. I'd now like to parse that page/ use something like BeautifulSoup on it. But I'm confused about how to call the resulting page.

My code so far:

```
textinput = open("1.txt", "r").read()
url = "http://www.example.com"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
sbox = driver.find_element_by_name("a")
sbox.send_keys(textinput)

submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="maincontent"]/form/input[5]')
submit.click()
```

Comment: when you enter the text then do a mouse click on some button like "go", "search" or something that will open the resultant page. Then you can use the source code of that page to extract data.
Please share your code

Comment: @Vipul Please find the added code. I'm able to get the result. But I need to parse it. I cannot manually copy the URL of the resulting page since I'd be doing this for hundreds of times. I'd like to automate it.

Comment: using `driver.source` you can get the source code

Comment: also you will not need to get source code or use beautifulsoup, parsing using selenium driver object itself is sufficient and very clean by using class, id, tag, xpath in `driver.find_element_by_<id,xpath...>` or 'driver.find_elements_by_<id,xpath...>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have clicked on the submit button using:

```
submit.click()
```

It automatically goes to the next page. So, to parse the resulting page, just make another:

```
whatimlookingfor = driver.find_element_by_id("myid")
```

---

```
submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="maincontent"]/form/input[5]')
# You are still on the first page
submit.click()
# You are now on the second page
whatimlookingfor = driver.find_element_by_id("myid")
```